# Correlation between $y_t$ and $y_{t - T}$

Tags: statistics, covariance, variance, correlation, expected-value

> Let $y_t = 0.8y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ where $\mathbb{E}[y_t]$ and $\mathrm{Var}[y_t]$ are constants (or $\mathbb{E}[y_t] = \mathbb{E}[y_{t-1}]$ and $\mathrm{Var}[y_t] = \mathrm{Var}[y_{t-1}]$) and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_t] = 0$ and $\mathrm{Var}[\epsilon_t] = 1$. Let $\rho(T)$ be the correlation between $y_t$ and $y_{t-T}$. Find $\rho(1)$ and $\rho(2)$.

Here is what I did for $\rho(1)$:

\begin{align}
\rho(1) &= Corr(y_{t-1}, y_{t})\\
  &= \dfrac{Cov(y_{t}, y_{t-1})}{(σ_{y_{t}}σ_{y_{t-1}})}\\
Cov(y_{t} , y_{t-1}) &= Cov(y_{t- 1}, 0.8y_{t- 1}+ε_{t})\\
      &= 0.8Cov(y_{t-1}, y_{t-1}) + Cov(y_{t-1}, \epsilon_{t})\\ 
      &= 0.8Var(yt-1)+ E((y_{t-1} - (0.8y_{t-1}))(\epsilon_{t} - E(\epsilon_{t})))\\
      &= 0.8Var(y_{t-1}) + E((0.2y_{t-1})(\epsilon_{t})) \\
         &= 0.8Var(y_{t-1}) + 0.2E(y_{t-1})E(\epsilon_{t})\\
                     &= 0.8Var(y_{t-1})\\
                     \implies \dfrac{\sqrt{(0.8Var(y_{t-1})))^2}}{Var(y_{t-1})^2)}&= \sqrt{0.8} = 0.8944
\end{align}
Did I do this right and if so, wouldn't ρ(2) be the same thing?

Comment: Not sure i get it. From your equation, it follows that $$\mathbb{E}[y_t] = \mathbb{E}[0.8 y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t] = 0.8 \mathbb{E}[y_{t-1}]$$ and yet you say $\mathbb{E}[y_t] = \mathbb{E}[y_{t-1}]$?

Comment: maybe I worded it wrong. Here is the exact wording from the question: The above time series is a strictly stationary sequence and each element is normally
distributed. Hence, E($y_t$) and Var($y_t$) are both constants. In particular, E($y_t$) = E($y_{t−1}$)
and Var($y_t$) = Var($y_{t−1}$).

Comment: Can you *please* write in MathJax, use `$a_b,a_{b+c}$` to get $a_b,a_{b+c}$

Comment: I'm trying, just learning how to use it

Comment: I changed your equations to use MathJax. Please take a look to see how it is done for future questions. How did you get $E((y_{t-1}-E(y_{t-1}))(\epsilon_t-E(\epsilon_t))) = E((y_{t-1}-0.8y_{t-1})(\epsilon_t-E(\epsilon_t)))$?